# ReactorNotRestartable error using CrawlerRunner in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I have used the same code as in the documentation with a small difference of instantiating the Crawlrunner with settings so that it doesn't miss the pipeline operations.If this is not used it will work fine but will skip the pipeline.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from forspef_scrapper import ForspefScrapper
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

d = runner.crawl(ForspefScrapper)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

Please suggest the cause of this and possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the callback for `reactor.stop` and you should not see that issue anymore. The reactor is designed to always be running

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to run the spider in a loop and if the callback is removed then it will not stop the crawler.

Comment: Do you have `reactor.stop` anywhere else in your project?